# FASM - how to do this without stack?

Tags: fasm

I wrote program that asking user for his name and displaying it on screen in FASM. I used stack, but I was wondering how I can do it without it.
This is working code:

```
format elf executable
entry _start

segment readable
    msg db 'What is your name: '
    msg.length = $-msg
    msg2 db 'Your name is: '
    msg2.length = $-msg2

segment readable writeable
    name db ?

segment readable executable
_start:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg
    mov edx,msg.length
    int 80h

    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,name
    mov edx,20
    int 80h

    push eax

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg2
    mov edx,msg2.length
    int 80h

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,name
    pop edx
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

I tried to do something like that:

```
format elf executable
entry _start

segment readable
    msg db 'What is your name: '
    msg.length = $-msg
    msg2 db 'Your name is: '
    msg2.length = $-msg2

segment readable writeable
    name db ?
    name.length db ?

segment readable executable
_start:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg
    mov edx,msg.length
    int 80h

    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,name
    mov edx,20
    int 80h

    mov dword [name.length],eax

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg2
    mov edx,msg2.length
    int 80h

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,name
    mov edx,dword [name.length]
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

Code is compiling without errors, but when I'm running it and when I input the name (e.g "debos") I'm getting:
`Your name is: d` and some weird char at the end
instead of:
`Your name is debos` like with the first code.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

*name* should be declared as an array of bytes, not as a single byte (db).

```
segment readable writeable
name db 100 dup(?)        ;or simply name rb 100
name.length dd ?
```

*name.length* should be a dword, not a byte. In FASM executable format, the code segment comes right after the last byte of the data segment, so it explains why it prints garbage characters because it overlaps. This is just the nature of the ELF executable format.

Answer (score 0):

`msg.length` is a constant so you can not overwrite it. If you want so, you should store this in a variable.